# Spree Commerce Number Input - JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am trying to add a simple plus/minus to an input box on each product on my categories page of my web app. It is for an add to cart.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div class="addqty">
        <div class="qtycontents">
            <a  class="add">+</a>
            <%= number_field_tag :quantity, 1, :min => 1 %>
            <a  class="minus">-</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my js:

```
$('.add').click(function () {
$(this).next('#quantity').val(parseInt($(this).next('#quantity').val(), 10) + 1);
});

$('.minus').click(function () {
$(this).prev('#quantity').val(parseInt($(this).prev('#quantity').val(), 10) - 1);
});
```

The issue I am having is unique. When clicking the "+" on the first product on my categories page, the input is not increased by 1, it is increased by the number of products on the page, minus 1. So, if there are 10 products on the page, and I click the "+" on the first product, my quantity in the input goes from 1 to 9, then to 18, then 27 etc. And the opposite when clicking "-". As you advance through the products, the increments become less - When on the third to last product, the qty increases by only 2.

Very confused. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that spree holds an add class for the products view and when you get the values for adding the quantity what you get is the items on the page, you should try changing the class names from your code and the **jquery** selectors.

Comment: thanks for the help! It ends up that all I had to do is use is .unbind() and it finally worked